# how to send fax using outlook interop library in c#?

Tags: c#, office-interop

we are trying a send a fax using c# code and we are looking to trigger it via microsoft outlook interop library. there are codes mail using outlook but we are looking for a code to trigger fax from outlook library.

Answer (score 0):

Sample Code :

```
using FAXCOMLib;
using FAXCOMEXLib;

FaxServerClass fs = new FaxServerClass();
fs.Connect(“<your_computer_name>”); //specifies the machinename
object obj = fs.CreateDocument(“<your_filename>”);
FaxDoc fd = (FaxDoc)obj;
fd.FaxNumber = “<your_fax_number_to_send_to”;
fd.RecipientName = “<your_recipients_name”;
int i = fd.Send();
MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());
fs.Disconnect();
```

for more details see [here](http://zakariarouf.wordpress.com/2008/11/09/sending-fax-using-c-and-net/)

Comment: is there any way to send fax without hardware requirement and just via outlook exchange interop code ?

Comment: I don't know that much but have you heard about the TAPI?
Using this you also can get a solution - just refer this http://forums.asp.net/t/1124088.aspx/1